# array merge but skipped on same key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
a = ["same", "same", "unique"];
b = [1,2,3];

var c = {};
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[a[i]] = b[i];
}

console.log(c);
```

In console I'm seeing `Object {same: 2, unique: 3}`, the 2 'same' key has became 1, I wonder why it don't produce `Object {same: 1,same: 2, unique: 3}`?

Comment: Two keys can't be same in an array and second time it's updating the first key value.

Comment: Because  the first call c['same']=1 is overriden by c['same']=2

Comment: @codehx so how to solve the problem?

Comment: @ajaykumartak so my merge is done wrongly, any other better way?

Comment: @aviate wong No way. You cannot have duplicate keys in object

Comment: What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: Depending on the use case you could use an array for the values: `{ same: [1, 2], unique: [3] }`

Comment: @Juan Object {same: 1,same: 2, unique: 3}

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because:
The first call `c['same']=1` is overriden by `c['same']=2`

### The solution

You want to put many values under same key means you want to put an array in that key instead of a single value.

So this will solve your problem:

```
a = ["same", "same", "unique"];
b = [1,2,3];

var c = {};
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[a[i]] ? c[a[i]].push(b[i]) : ( c[a[i]] = [ b[i] ] );
}

console.log(c);
```

Then look below the structure of your map( `c` variable):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> the 2 'same' key has became 1

Yes, an object can't contain two properties with the same name, so in your sample you're writing twice to the "same" key, and the second value (2) is overwriting the first value (1).

The reason is simple. If you could have something like `a = { same: 1, same: 2, unique: 3 }`, what would the value of `a.same` be?

Comment: how to produce this Object {same: 1,same: 2, unique: 3}

Comment: That's not possible. The closest you can get is to have an array of array: `[[ "same", 1 ], [ "same", 2 ], [ "unique", 3 ]]`, or an array of objects with a single key each, like `[ { same: 1 }, { same: 2 }, { unique: 3 } ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the arrays if you want and you get the output Object {1: same,2: same, 3: unique}